# New to Drupal 10.2.4. Looking to Consume RESTful data, and populate content on page. Most articles seem outdated or so far, don't give clear answer

Tags: ajax

Given JSON response from external API like this:
{
"Id": "Dr1",
"DoctorInfo": {
"firstName": "Donald",
"lastName": "Duck"
},
"PatientList": [
{
"Id": "Pt1",
"Name": "Patient 1",
"AppointmentDate": "04/01/2024"
},
{
"Id": "Pt2",
"Name": "Patient 2",
"AppointmentDate": "04/02/2024"
}
]
}

What modules/content type, php code, etc. would I use.  I thought this would be a no-brainer.